# Selenium cannot get webpage content on Linux but work well on Windows for a specific website

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am web-scraping Bitcoin quotations from [**Coinsuper**](https://www.coinsuper.com/trade/). It is a javascript page. When I first develop my code on Windows using **Python 3.7**, **Selenium**, and **Chromium**, it works well.

I want to deploy this code on my server to fetch data continuously. However, it doesn't work under Linux.

I am sure my code can work, at least on most websites, including [Apple](https://www.apple.com), [Google](https://www.google.com), [Baidu](https://www.baidu.com), [Xueqiu](https://xueqiu.com), etc.

- For the OS system, I have tried Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04.
- For webdriver, I have tried both Chrome and Firefox.
- For webdriver parameters, I have tried:

  1. Add header, including `fake-useragent`
  2. Ignore SSL certificate
  3. Disable GPU

These make no difference.

I think it might because [**Coinsuper**](https://www.coinsuper.com/trade/) has some anti-scraping strategy. But I am also confused why the similar code can work on Windows but not on Linux. Are there any differences that might cause this situation?

The code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Only included in Linux version
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Only included in Linux version
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.coinsuper.com/trade')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You should add Chromium driver path in `webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver",options=chrome_options)` where **/usr/bin/chromedriver** is driver path .

Comment: Thanks, @bharatk ! I have added the webdriver in the path. It shows no difference in specifying the path. Apple, Google can still return normal content while [Coinsuper](https://www.coinsuper.com/trade/) cannot.

Comment: web browser on different system has different `User-Agent` header. This way server may block access for some systems. Do you have problem to open  this page directly in web browser in Linux ?

Comment: what does `Doesn't work` mean?

Comment: I run it with Firefox webdriver on Linux Mint 19.1 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) and it display page_source. I can't check if content is correct but when I run it without `--headless` then I see all in browser.

Comment: Thanks, @furas! I have only run my server in the command line. I will try to install a GUI and see whether the webdriver can get content.

Comment: If your server is in the cloud maybe coinsuper blacklisted your IP for previous abuse, or even the whole subnet for your provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the one who asks this question. Thank you all for helping me! Finally, I have solved this problem.

- @furas showed that my code could actually get responses from [Coinsuper](https://www.coinsuper.com/trade/).
- @Dalvenjia inspired me that this might be caused by IP blacklist, which is most probable for the cloud servers. And yes, I am using a cloud server.

Here is the solution:

1. Start a [Shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks) **server** from my home IP address, or use any proxy you have.
2. Start [Shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks) **client** on the server:
3. Add one more argument to ChromeDriver in Python script:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:xxxx')
```

Now I can get contents by bypassing the IP blacklist.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use WebDriverManager dependency:

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

By using WebDriverManager, you didn't need to download or manage drivers path in code.

Comment: I don't think it is solution for problem. It is rather good for comment, not for answer. Downvote.

Comment: that's a great library dude but not aplicable here